# Make Text Font Dynamic Within the border of the Parent Div

Tags: javascript, css

I have this HTML element.

```
<div id="myid_templates_preview_text_1" style="transform: rotate(0deg); border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; left: 64.5px; top: 144.984px; width: 117px; height: 42px; z-index: 1;">
    <p>
        <span style="color: #000000; font-size: large;">Sample Very Very Long Line Of Text.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Below is the output look:

[image]

I want to adjust the text font not to exceed the borders of the div. How will I do this.

UPDATE 1:

Actually, Im working on a layout designer app, thus the html structure must not be modified. The HTML content above is dynamically design by a user. Below is another sample of HTML structure.

```
<div id="myid_templates_preview_text_2" style="transform: rotate(0deg); border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; left: 62px; top: 84px; width: 87px; height: 97px; z-index: 1;">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
       <span style="font-size: medium;">
           <strong>Sample Very Very Long Line Of Text.</strong>
       </span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="font-size: small;">
            <strong>Sample Very Very Long Line Of Text.</strong>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, albeit inefficient and lazy is to recursively resize the text until it fits. I slightly modified your markup to remove the p tag and make it more readable:

```
#myid_templates_preview_text_1{
  transform: rotate(0deg); 
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 64.5px; 
  top: 144.984px; 
  width: 117px; 
  height: 42px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#myid_templates_preview_text_1 span{
  color: #000000; 
  font-size: large;
}
```

.

```
<div id="myid_templates_preview_text_1">
    <span>Sample Very Very Long Line Of Text.</span>
</div>
```

Then the code:

```
function sizeTextToDiv(){
    var wrapper = $('#myid_templates_preview_text_1');
    var wh = wrapper.height(); //get the height of the div
    var s = wrapper.find('span').first();
    var ph = s.height(); //get the height of the text

    if (ph > wh){
        //still too big
        var fs = parseInt(s.css('font-size'));
        if (isNaN(fs)) fs = 32; //default if non-numeric
        fs--; //decrease the font size
        s.css('font-size',fs);
        sizeTextToDiv(); //do it again
    }
}

$(function(){
    sizeTextToDiv();
});
```

Working jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8boxt0xk/

**UPDATE 1:**

Since you can't edit the markup, here's an updated function that will resize the fonts and keep them in proportion. I would add a margin 0 to your p tags to make it fit nicely in the div though:

```
function sizeTextToDiv(){
    var wrapper = $('#myid_templates_preview_text_2');
    var wh = wrapper.height();
    var ph = 0;

    wrapper.find('p').each(function(){
        ph += $(this).height();
    });

    console.log(wh, ph);
    if (ph > wh){
        //overflow
        wrapper.find('span').each(function(){
           var s = $(this);
           var sh = parseInt(s.css('font-size'));
           if (isNaN(sh)) sh = 28;
           sh--;
           s.css('font-size', sh);
        });
        debugger;
        sizeTextToDiv();  
    }
}
```

jsfiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/8boxt0xk/2/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate. I updated my post above, I hope you could still address my concern.

Comment: Done. That should account for multiple children under the div.

Answer (score 0):

just adjust the width and the height:

```html
<div id="myid_templates_preview_text_1" style="transform: rotate(0deg); border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; left: 64.5px; top: 144.984px; width: 117px; height: 80px; z-index: 1;">
    <p>
        <span style="color: #000000; font-size: large;">Sample Very Very Long Line Of Text.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```